# Android Studio Hedgehog - Unable to switch between recent files using CTRL+TAB/SHIFT+TAB

Tags: windows, android-studio, ide, settings, keymapping

I had a problem with Android Studio after I updated to the latest version *Hedgehog 2023.1.1*, which I can't switch between recent files using the CTRL+TAB / SHIFT+TAB shortcut

I checked the *keymap* in the settings, and the shortcut should be applied, Is there anyone who has this problem, and **is there any way to solve it?**

[image]

I think this is a bug, and I created an issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/314340463)
please if you have the same problem make a vote in the issue-tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/314340463), maybe Google will notice the issue and solve it, I regretted updating because of this problem.